# How can I change the color of a Link in React with Material-UI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-router-dom

I'm not able to change the color of a Link inside a Button. When I apply the secondary color to the Button, it doesn't take effect. In other components it does work this way.

```
<AppBar position='fixed'>
                <Toolbar>
                    <Button color='secondary'>
                        <Link to="/">Home</Link>
                    </Button>
                </Toolbar>
</AppBar>
```

In App.js I create the custom Theme and wrap it around all components with 
`<ThemeProvider theme={customTheme}>`

App.js:

```
const customTheme = createMuiTheme({
    palette: {
        primary: {
            main: '#36454B',
            contrastText: '#fff',
        },
        secondary: {
            light: '#55dab3',
            main: '#00a883',
            dark: '#007856',
            contrastText: '#000',
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Is specifying `color` property on the Button itself a requirement? Link component has its own `color` property that lets you utilize your theme the way you intend to.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you can do is pass `component={Link}` to button, so it will render the `Link` as it base component. See the [docs](https://material-ui.com/api/button/#props).

```
<Button color='secondary' href="/" component={Link}>
    Home
</Button>
```

Comment: Will this work with Next link?

Comment: @AliWaqas there's only one way to find out

Answer (score 10):

I know this is old, but you can change the color of all Link objects in the theme using the action object within the theme object (Material-UI v4 and MUI v5):

```
// Material-UI v4
import lightBlue from '@material-ui/core/colors/lightBlue'

// or for MUI v5
import { lightBlue } from '@mui/material/colors'

...
 palette: {
   primary { ... },
   secondary { ... },
   action: {
      active: lightBlue[200],
      activeOpacity: 1,
      hover: lightBlue[100],
      hoverOpacity: 0.7,
      focus: lightBlue[600],
      focusOpacity: 1,
      selected: lightBlue[300],
      selectedOpacity: 1
    },
    ...
```

Comment: Might be trivial to others, but make sure you `import { lightBlue } from '@mui/material/colors';`

Comment: Good call. Cheers! 

Comment: minor typo:  this seems to be activatedOpacity (with a d) instead of activeOpacity for MUI 4

Comment: say @DBrown how did you find this gem?

i just searched the mui docs and googled and all that and no dice.

Comment: @arigold Yeah, the theme details are definite hidden. So much so, in the Material-UI 3/4 days, I actually had to check the source of createTheme function. Now you can simply inspect the theme object in state when running your project, and see all of the default props for the theme object. You can now find all of these in the Default Theme Viewer in the docs: https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/default-theme/

Answer (score 0):

This seem to work for me, might not be the best way:

```
import { Link as RouterLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import { 
  Link,
} from '@mui/material';
```

...

```
const buttonSx = {
                px: 6,
                textAlign: 'center',
              };

              const buttonProps = {
                key: link.id,
                variant: link.outlined ? 'outlined' : 'contained',
                className: 'book-grid__button',
              };
              return link.isExternal ? (
                <Button
                  href={link.Link}
                  rel="noreferrer noopener"
                  target="_blank"
                  {...buttonProps}
                  sx={buttonSx}
                >
                  {link.Text}
                </Button>
              ) : (
                <Button
                  to={link.Link}
                  component={RouterLink}
                  {...buttonProps}
                  sx={buttonSx}
                >
                  {link.Text}
                </Button>
              );
```